# misplaced subplots using Venn diagrams and GridSpec [python / matplotlib]

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout

I'm having troubles creating a grid layout plot using two different venn packages, the first one is the matplot-venn and the other is the venn package to intersect more than 3 subsets. The problem with the venn package is that its creating a new figure and axis, therefore I'm creating all plots in a function and then add them to my composite figure. The initial grid is placed properly (img1), also when adding the subplots with the corresponding gridSpec the coordinates are correct, but when plotting the layout is completely off (img2).first of all it seems only half of the figure x axis is used and the 4 small venns should be roughly the same size and rows as the two bigger ones on the left.

img1 correct grid layout
[image]

img2 wrong layout
[image]

I tried several other things e.g. adjusting parameters such as autoscaling, squeeze, clipping or subplot specs etc. , unfortunately all with the same result.

I'm working on a server and connecting via ssh plus xforwarding, either using a mac (quartz) or windows (xming) and the issue is present on both machines.

I'm new to python plotting so any help or suggestions are highly appreciated

thanks a lot

```
import os
import re
import copy
import pandas as pd
import venn # for 4 way venns, non proportional
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# for ssh connections through windows using a non-interactive backend
# import matplotlib
# matplotlib.use('Agg')

def extractORFName(orfList):
    return set([re.sub("(.*)_[0-9]*aa.*","\\1",x) for x in orfList])

def plotValidatedOverlap(orfList,nameList):
    labels = venn.get_labels(orfList, fill=['number'])
    figX, axVenn = venn.venn5(labels, names=nameList,fontsize=8)
    axVenn.get_legend().remove()
    v_human = plotVenn3(orfList[0:3],nameList[0:3])
    v_mouse = plotVenn3(orfList[1:4],nameList[1:4])
    plt.close(figX)
    return (axVenn, v_human, v_mouse)

def plotVenn3(orfList,nameList):
    fig ,ax = plt.subplots()
    out = venn3(orfList,nameList,normalize_to=0.75)
    for text in out.set_labels:
        text.set_fontsize(8)
    for text in out.subset_labels:
        if text is not None:
            text.set_fontsize(6)
    plt.close(fig)
    return ax

def copyElement(axList,gs,fig):
    for idx in range(0,len(axList)):
        print("\n\n### processing idx: %s" % idx)
        pos = gs[idx].get_position(fig)
        ax = copy.copy(axList[idx])
        ax.figure = fig
        ax.set_position(pos)
        ax.set_subplotspec(gs[idx])
        fig.add_subplot(ax,aspect='equal',autoscale_on=True)
        fig.axes[idx].set_clip_on(False)
        print("axes positions:\t%s" % str(fig.axes[idx].get_position()))
        print("gs position:'t%s" % str(pos))
        #fig1.canvas.draw()
        #input("next axes")

#### data input to create orfList (list of sets as subsets) and nameList (labels of subsets)

fig1, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100, figsize=(18,8),num="venn")#, squeeze=False, constrained_layout=True)
fig1.axes[0].remove()
gs = GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=3, width_ratios=[2,1,1], figure=fig1)
figsToPlot = sum([ list(plotValidatedOverlap(orfList[type],nameList)) for type in orfList ],[])
fig1.clear()
fig1.suptitle(cellType + "_" + method + "_overlap")
fig1.canvas.draw()
copyElement(figsToPlot,gs,fig1)
fig1.tight_layout()
fig1.canvas.draw()
```